# keep getting upload php $_FILES error = 3 (partially uploaded)

Tags: php, file-upload, yii, yii-extensions, dropzone.js

I am using dropzone extension for Yii framework to upload some files by registered users. Everything working well but some users for some files that they trying to upload it's return error = 3 which it's happens when the uploaded file was only partially uploaded.

```
$file_error = $_FILES['Project']['error']['file'];
if ($file_error != 0) {
            mail('myemail@gmail.com', 'fileError',json_encode($_FILES['Project']));
}
```

i'am receiving a lot of emails from this function

JSON received

```
{"name":{"file":"3.jpg"},"type":{"file":""},"tmp_name":{"file":""},"error":{"file":3},"size":{"file":0}}
```

### how can i debug this error and know the cases that make this error happened ?

This error happened 
1- if the user refresh the page while uploading.
2- if the user cancel the upload (there is no cancel option in my site).
3- if the internet connection lost while uploading.

I'm still looking for other cases.

Comment: Offtopic, but `if (!$file_error == 0) {` should be `if ($file_error != 0) {`.

Comment: @CharlotteDunois Why? OP wants to be emailed when there is an error, not if ther eis no error.

Comment: yes thanks, but the same result in my case

Comment: @Ohgodwhy If there is no error, `$file_error` is equal to 0.

Comment: yes 0 means there is no errors check this [link](http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.errors.php)

Answer (score 4):

in my case, the "partially uploaded" problem happened when uploading medium/large files using a slow internet connection.

The solution that works for me was set some Apache configurations in httpd.conf file:

```
TimeOut 300
KeepAliveTimeout 10
RequestReadTimeout handshake=0 header=20-1200,MinRate=200 body=20,MinRate=200
```

I hope it help.

Comment: This saved my day! For a PHP developer such a setting is quite obscure, as changing the PHP ini settings didn't do anything. I only used the `RequestReadTimeout` setting btw.

Answer (score 1):

As php documentation says, this error is

`UPLOAD_ERR_PARTIAL is given when the mime boundary is not found after the file data. 
A possibly cause for this is that the upload was cancelled by the user (pressed ESC, etc).`

Also there are some more variants to check:

1. Permissions are wrong (i doubt, cause it will break all users).
2. Not enough free space on server.
3. This error occures when uploading from iOS.
4. This error can occure when uploading folder (due to browser limitations). On Mac OSX it occures 100%.

So this is possible errors to check. Hope this will help.

Comment: it's not permissions issues for sure and there is a lot of space on the server. i will check on ios but if it's ios issues how can i solve it ?

Comment: actually idk how to fix it. Maybe it's working now, adding `header('Connection: close');` didn't helped me. I just left it, cause it was not frequent error. The problem was almost year ago, so maybe it's fixed now.

Comment: i will try to change header connection to close it's "Keep-Alive" now

Comment: close connection doesn't solve it, and the issues occurs on windows also

Comment: i'm uploading from iOS and getting this error, how to fix?

Comment: I have the same problem with all files larger than 10K. See this: http://www.programering.com/q/MzNyYzMwATE.html None of the solutions there helped.

Comment: Also, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35006344/php-upload-file-error-code-3

Comment: One possible problem with IOS is it's browsers can kill an ongoing ajax connection (like a file upload for instance) if the browser loses focus. Examples are hitting the home button in the middle of an upload, or opening the file browser or camera for a second upload.