# Image uploads, the next day it fails to upload

Tags: php, html

I've followed this tutorial https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_file_upload.asp to upload an image. This works and the image is in the directory. I can then delete it from the directory, run the code again and it will reupload the image.

The strange thing is the next day when I run it again (no code altered) I get:

```
 $_FILES["imageToUpload"]["error"] = 3
```

when uploading the same image as yesterday. When I try it with a different image I get no errors and it all works. Then the next day the new image will come across the same issue (The original image still won't work).

From what I've found this error code is to do with a partial upload problem. The answer in this question lists some possible issues [keep getting upload php $_FILES error = 3 (partially uploaded)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25475805/keep-getting-upload-php-files-error-3-partially-uploaded), but these don't seem to match my issue

I also tried renaming the image to upload so that it would save as a new file , in case it's still on the virtual machine somehow, but it still has the same error.

Any help or advise would be appreciated. Thanks in advance

Comment: error:  `UPLOAD_ERR_PARTIAL

    Value: 3; The uploaded file was only partially uploaded.`

Comment: Can you copy the file to the location (without using upload) ?

Comment: Not sure on how I'd do that. The image is on my local machine.

Comment: what about ftp?

Comment: I'll give it a go

Comment: No it won't let me transfer the image that isn't working. I get "System Error. Code 59". It will let me transfer other images though