# PHP - Error 3 showing while uploading file greater than 64kb

Tags: php, file-upload

I'm trying to upload a file "profile-cover.png" which is 91kb in size. Hence the file is getting error code 3 as it is not less than 64 kb. My settings in php.ini is:

```
upload_max_filesize = 10M
post_max_size = 10M
```

So I think there is no error in settings. The error print is given below:

```
([upload] => Array
    (
        [name] => Array
            (
                [0] => profile-cover.png
            )

        [type] => Array
            (
                [0] => 
            )

        [tmp_name] => Array
            (
                [0] => 
            )

        [error] => Array
            (
                [0] => 3
            )

        [size] => Array
            (
                [0] => 0
            )

    )
)
```

*Here is my code:*

```
$title = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $title);
$des = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $des);
$file_count = count($_FILES['upload']['name']);
for($i=0;$i<$file_count;$i++){
     $extensions = array('jpg','png','gif','jpeg');
     $file_ext = explode('.',$_FILES['upload']['name'][$i]);
     $file_ext = strtolower(end($file_ext));

     if(in_array($file_ext,$extensions)){
        $newFile = 'uploads/'.$name=$userId.'_'.date('m-d-Y_his').'.'.$file_ext;
     if(move_uploaded_file ( $_FILES['upload']['tmp_name'][$i], $newFile)) 
      {
         $date = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
         $sql = "INSERT INTO picture (Album_Id,FileName,Title,Description,Date_Added) VALUES ('$albumId','$newFile','$title','$des','$date')";
         if(mysqli_query($con, $sql)){
              $insertErr = "Image uploaded successfully.";
         }else{
              $insertErr = "There was an error while uploading the images.";
         }
      }
   }else{
          $uploadErr = "'".$_FILES['upload']['name'][$i]."' unsupported extension";
   }
}
```

Can someone help please?

Comment: Check post_max_size

Comment: Please refer the below links for error value (3) > UPLOAD_ERR_PARTIAL https://www.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.errors.php... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25475805/keep-getting-upload-php-files-error-3-partially-uploaded

Comment: Possible duplicate of [keep getting upload php $\_FILES error = 3 (partially uploaded)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25475805/keep-getting-upload-php-files-error-3-partially-uploaded)

Comment: Kindly post some of your code and also refer to this [ask].

Answer (score 0):

**PHP - Error 3 causes :**

1.Permissions not there.

2.Space problem on server .

3.It may be an error occures when uploading

Comment: 1. I have given full control to the uploads folder.
2. There is enough space to upload a 91kb file
3. The error occurs whenever I try to upload a file which is greater than 64kb